# How do I strip the query (used for GET parameters) from a URL?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I'm building a small REST service to authorize users into my app.

At one point, the UIWebView I'm using to authorize the user, will go to https://myautholink.com/login.php. This page sends a JSON response with an authorization token. The thing about this page is that it receives some data via GET via my authorization form. I cannot use PHP sessions because you arrive to this page via:

```
header("location:https://myautholink.com/login.php?user_id=1&machine_id=machine_id&machine_name=machine_name&app_id=app_id");
```

Since the header function sends in headers, I cannot do a `session_start();` at the same time.

I can get the UIWebView's request URL without a problem using the delegate methods:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [webView request];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[request URL] relativeString]);
    if([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:SPAtajosLoginLink])
    {
        //Store auth token and dismiss auth web view.
    }
}
```

The thing is none of the NSURL methods seem to return the "clean" link without the parameters. I have looked at all the NSURL url-string related methods:

```
- (NSString *)absoluteString;
- (NSString *)relativeString; // The relative portion of a URL.  If baseURL is nil, or if the receiver is itself absolute, this is the same as absoluteString
```

But absoluteString is always the full URL with the GET parameters and relativeString is always nil.

I'm scratching my head with this and I can't seem to find the solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than mess about with your own string manipulation, hand off to `NSURLComponents`:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url];
components.query = nil;     // remove the query
components.fragments = nil; // probably want to strip this too for good measure
url = [components URL];
```

On iOS 6 and earlier, you can bring in [`KSURLComponents`](http://www.mikeabdullah.net/ksurlcomponents.html) to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 6):

Example: http://www.google.com:80/a/b/c;params?m=n&o=p#fragment

Use these methods of NSURL:

```
         scheme: http
           host: www.google.com
           port: 80
           path: /a/b/c
   relativePath: /a/b/c
parameterString: params
          query: m=n&o=p
       fragment: fragment
```

Or, in iOS 7, build a NSURLComponents instance, then use the methods scheme, user, password, host, port, path, query, fragment, to extract part of the URL as strings. Then build the base URL back.

```
NSString* baseURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@/%@", URL.scheme, ...
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString];
```

Comment: Thanks. For the curious, I ended up rebuilding the string like this: `NSString *basicPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@:%@%@", requestUrl.scheme, requestUrl.host, requestUrl.port, requestUrl.path];`

Comment: Thanks for bringing `NSURLComponents` to my attention!

Comment: Rather this:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@%@", requestURL.scheme, requestURL.host, requestURL.path]

Answer (score 5):

To update this answer for iOS 7 onwards:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL: url resolvingAgainstBaseURL: NO];
components.query = nil;     // remove the query
components.fragment = nil; // probably want to strip this too for good measure
url = [components URL];
```

Please note also that there is no 'fragments' property. It's just 'fragment'.

Otherwise, this method is great. Much better than worrying about putting the URL back together properly with string manips.